# Get value of snap.svg object in backbone view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, svg

In the following code I want to create the functionality of a like button when the `svg` symbol is clicked. I am having trouble getting the value of `sPaper`, `sPolyFill` and `sPolyEmpty`.
So far as is they return undefined.

I need to integrate the `symbolAnim` function into the `like` and `unlike` function. How can I do this?

```
var LikeButtonView = BaseButtonView.extend({ 

    template: _.template($('#like-button-test').html()),
    sPaper: null,
    sPolyFill: null,
    sPolyEmpty: null,

    initialize: function (options) {
      BaseButtonView.prototype.initialize.apply(this, [options]); // inherit from BaseButtonView
      this.butn = $("button.heart-icon", this.$el);
      this.sPaper = Snap(heartIcon.get(0));
      this.sPolyFill = sPaper.select('.symbol-solid');
      this.sPolyEmpty = sPaper.select('.symbol-empty');
    },

    like: function () {
        console.log("Like clicked");
        if (this.butn.hasClass("isLiked")) {
            this.unlike();
        } else if (this.butn.hasClass("unliked")){
            this.butn.removeClass("unLiked");
            this.butn.addClass("isLiked");
            this.addBlur();
        }
    },

    unlike: function () {
        this.butn.removeClass('isLiked');
        this.butn.addClass("unLiked");
        this.addBlur(); 
    },

    symbolAnim: function(heartIcon, isLiked) {

        if (isLiked === false) {
            sPolyFill.animate({ transform: 't9,0' }, 300, mina.easeinout);
            sPolyEmpty.animate({ transform: 't-9,0' }, 300, mina.easeinout);
        } else {
            sPolyFill.animate({ transform: 't0,0'}, 300, mina.easeinout);
            sPolyEmpty.animate({ transform: 't0,0' }, 300, mina.easeinout);
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I got the object by targeting `this.butn`

```
initialize: function (options) {
      BaseButtonView.prototype.initialize.apply(this, [options]); // inherit from BaseButtonView
      this.butn = $("button.heart-icon", this.$el);
      this.svgNode = this.butn.find("svg").get(0);
      this.sPaper = Snap(this.svgNode);
      this.sPolyFill = this.sPaper.select('.symbol-solid');
      this.sPolyEmpty = this.sPaper.select('.symbol-empty');
      console.log(this.sPaper);
```

Now I need to implement the functionality of `symbolAnim` in the `like` and `unlike` funcitons

Answer (score -1):

For my like button function, which is triggered in the event has as `"click selector": "like"`, I have come up with the following. However this only works once. So when I click the button the first time it adds the class `liked` and removes the class `unliked`, which is the default for the html element. Then when it is clicked again, it removes the `liked` class and adds the `unliked` class. So far it works as desired. 
The problem is when I try to click it again, to like it again, and nothing happens. It doesn't call the like function anymore and the class remains the `unliked`.

What is causing this problem and how can I fix it?

```
like: function () {     
    if (this.butn.hasClass("liked")) {
        this.unlike();
    } else if (this.butn.hasClass("unliked")) {
        this.controller();
        console.log("Like clicked");
    }
},

controller: function () {
    this.butn.removeClass("unliked");
    this.butn.addClass("liked");
    this.sPolyFill.animate({ transform: 't9,0' }, 300, mina.easeinout);
    this.sPolyEmpty.animate({ transform: 't-9,0' }, 300, mina.easeinout);
},

unlike: function () {
    this.butn.removeClass('liked');
    this.butn.addClass("unLiked");
    this.sPolyFill.animate({ transform: 't0,0'}, 300, mina.easeinout);
    this.sPolyEmpty.animate({ transform: 't0,0' }, 300, mina.easeinout);
    console.log("Unliked"); 
}
```